# Image overlay toggling

Tags: jquery, css, overlay

When I hover over an image, I want an onverlay to appear with some random html of my choice. I want the overlay to lay exactly over the image.

I know what my problem is, but I'm not exactly sure how to fix it. My problem is that when I create the overlay from hovering on the image, I'm no longer hovering over the image, I'm hovering on the newly created overlay. This makes the *mouseleave* event on the image fire sooner than wanted. I really want it to fire when I leave the overlay. And I can't seem to get the *mouseleave* event to work on the overlay selector.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/05a0838e/6/

I'm open to any type of suggestions for a fix: CSS, JS, Plugins, or a mix of those. I just need to be able to create the content of the overlay like I have in my JSFiddle:

```
$(this).after("<div class='team-overlay-mask'><div class='team-overlay-border'><div class='team-overlay-content-wrap text-center'><h2>" + name + "</h2><h4>" + title + "</h4></div></div></div>");
```

Some Things I've tried with no luck:

```
$(".team-overlay-mask").mouseleave(function(){
     $(this).remove();
});
```

*event.stopPropagation();* inside the initial hover event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you just change up the `mouseleave` method to be like the following?

```
  $(".wrap").mouseleave(function() {
    $('.team-overlay-mask', this).remove();
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5u2qzekm/

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Didn't think about using mouseleave on the parent/wrap element.